# sapui5 geomap crashing ipad

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, sapui5

I am developing a simple sapui5 website that has to work on both mobile devices (ipad) and desktop browsers. That should, in theory, be no problem. I am however encountering a really nasty problem that I am not able to figure out. 
I have a simple master/detail view with several tabs. One of the tabs is containing a geomap. The website runs fine on several desktop browsers. When I try to run it on ipad (safari/chrome/firefox - IOS8) it causes to crash the whole browser as soon as I open the tab containing the map. 
Since the whole browser crashes I can not give any additional information as error messages or other stuff. 
This problem even occurs for me when I just add an IconTab with a geomap in it (no spots, no routes, nothing).

Can anyone give me an advice on how to find out what the problem is or steps on how the nail the problem?

Comment: Do you have a small prototype that we can use to reproduce your problem? E.g. a small JSBin/JSFiddle/Plunker.

Comment: Can you open any of these on your iPad? I had no problems on mine https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/entity/sap.ui.vbm.GeoMap/samples

Comment: Applying an iOS update today solved the problem. I can not reproduce the problem anymore.However, the SAPUI5 explored example caused the iPad to crash as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact reason for the problem, but doing an IOS upgrade solved the problem.